# How to measure total execution time of a parallel task or multi-thread program in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, stopwatch, execution-time

I am a novice in C#/.NET. Here I am trying to run the following parallel tasks and measure the total execution time.

But after running the code the execution time is showing just > 6 ms which is way less than it is supposed to be. I am not sure if there is any misplacing of the Stopwatch() function that's giving this unexpected result.

Your help will be appreciated :

```
namespace Tests
{
    class Prod
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
            s.Start();
            {
                Task T1 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine("Test1:" + i);
                });
                Task T2 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine("Test2:" + i);
                });
                Task T3 = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine("Test3:" + i);
                });

            }
            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit");
            Console.ReadKey();


            Console.WriteLine("Total Task Ellapsed time -> {0}", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You could use WaitAll to wait for all tasks to complete. Task.WaitAll(T1,T2,T3);

Answer (score 1):

You need a [Task.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___) before the stop of the `Stopwatch` (`s.Stop()` in your code)

for example:

```
Task.WaitAll(T1,T2,T3);
s.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to wait for all Tasks to be completed using [Task.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8)

```
Task.WaitAll(T1,T2,T3);
```

Complete Code

```
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();
    {
            Task T1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine("Test1:" + i);
            });
            Task T2 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine("Test2:" + i);
            });
            Task T3 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 5000; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine("Test3:" + i);
            });

            Task.WaitAll(T1,T2,T3); // Change here
   }
   s.Stop();
   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit");
   Console.WriteLine("Total Task Ellapsed time -> {0}", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```